# Data is not being inserted into second table (MYSQLi)

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I am using the code below that uploads a file and inserts data into the "Image" table using mysqli:

```
<?php
session_start();

$username="xxx";
$password="xxx";
$database="mobile_app";

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $database);

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    die();
}

$result = 0;

//UPLOAD IMAGE FILE

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"], "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);

$result = 1;

//INSERT INTO IMAGE DATABASE TABLE

$imagesql = "INSERT INTO Image (ImageFile) VALUES (?)";

if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($imagesql)) {
    // Handle errors with prepare operation here
}

//Dont pass data directly to bind_param store it in a variable
$insert->bind_param("s", $img);

//Assign the variable
$img = 'ImageFiles/' . $_FILES['fileImage']['name'];

$insert->execute();

//RETRIEVE IMAGEID FROM IMAGE TABLE

$lastID = $mysqli->insert_id;

//INSERT INTO IMAGE_QUESTION DATABASE TABLE

$imagequestionsql = "INSERT INTO Image_Question (ImageId, SessionId, QuestionId) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";


if (!$insertimagequestion = $mysqli->prepare($imagequestionsql)) {
    // Handle errors with prepare operation here
}

$sessid =  $_SESSION['id'] . ($_SESSION['initial_count'] > 1 ? $_SESSION['sessionCount'] : '');

$insertimagequestion->bind_param("sss", $lastID, $sessid, $_POST['numQuestion'][$i]);

$insertimagequestion->execute();

//IF ANY ERROR WHILE INSERTING DATA INTO EITHER OF THE TABLES
if ($insert->errno) {
  // Handle query error here
}

$insert->close();

if ($insertimagequestion->errno) {
  // Handle query error here
}

$insertimagequestion->close();

}

}
?>
```

So for example if I insert 2 images "cat.png" and "dog.png" into "Image" Database table, it will insert it like this:

```
ImageId         ImageFile

220             cat.png
221             dog.png
```

(ImageId is an auto increment)

Anyway what I want to do is that when a file is uploaded, not only is the data inserted into the table above, but I want to also be able to retrieve the ImageId that was inserted above and place it in the "Image_Question" table below so it would be like this:

```
 ImageId         SessionId      QuestionId

    220             cat.png      1
    221             dog.png      4
```

The problem is that it is not inserting any data into the second table "Image_Question", does anyone know why it is not inserting any data? There is no errors in the php file.

To upload a file, the user selects a file for the ajax uploader in the "QandATable.php" page, when the user clicks on upload, using AJAX it will go onto the imageupload.php page and does the uploading there. So the problem I have is that no errors will appear as they are on seperate pages.

Comment: You should probably actually handle the errors instead of just ignoring them.  That will probably tell you what's wrong.

Comment: `$_POST['numQuestion'][$i]` - Where did you set `$i`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, save the insert ID gained from your record addition (after the $insert->execute):

```
$lastID = $mysqli->insert_id;
```

Then reference $lastID later.

To pull up my comment from below:

```
$lastID = $insert->insert_id;
```

I think it's to do with swapping the handle names around - $mysqli, $insert etc.

Hope I read the question correctly...

Comment: So for the bind_params for ImageID in the second query, is it simplay $lastID? E.G: `$insertimagequestion->bind_param("sss", $lastID, $sessid, $_POST['numQuestion'][$i]);`

Comment: Isnt the image id the 1st parameter? $insertimagequestion->bind_param($lastID, $sessid, $_POST['numQuestion'][$i]);

Comment: Yes but need to use `sss` when bind parameters to show that I am binding three parameters. Each s represents a parameter

Comment: Since the IDs are numbers, shouldn't it be `iii` rather than `sss`?

Comment: I just noticed that in your example, SessionID is a string like "dog.png", not an integer (it's confusing to call that an ID). So the bind parameter should be `isi`.

Comment: Ok, try this:  $lastID = $insert->insert_id;

Answer (score 1):

Check for `500 Error` responses in Firebug -> Net tab/Chrome Developer tools -> Network tab . Even if nothing is returned as text, this will help you debug a syntax/semantic error as opposed to a logical error.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, what happens when you echo $lastID? Do you get a value output to the screen?

If not, we need to fix that first so that $lastID is returning the correct value.

Your insert code appears to be correct.

Comment: When I echo $lastID, nothing appears on screen, but if you read the last paragraph to my question, I don't know if anything would output on screen as the uploading occurs on a seperate page

Comment: @user1394925: you can always observe the upload script's response using your browser's developer tools or other tools like [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Answer (score 0):

You should get the Last inserted ID from first table and insert into your 2nd table (Image_Question) .

I Don't know the PHP coding, but this task is simple as well.Because this operation will be executed inside DAO class.So, No matter whether it is PHP or JAVA.

Answer (score 0):

If the second insertion fails, then

```
if ($insertimagequestion->error) {
    // Handle query error here
   echo $insertimagequestion->error;
}
```

This should tell you what the Error being thrown from the execution of the statement is.

Your PHP code seems fine, the error could be due to a Foreign key constraints or any other constraints on your DB Tables.

**PS:** I think you should validate the type of files you allow to be uploaded so people can't upload *.php or *.js files, this can lead to catastrophic XSS attacks.
Also try to avoid using the same filename as uploaded by the user, you may want to prefix with some random variable, so you can now have

```
//notice uniqid(time()) for randomness, also move the declaration of $img higher
//Assign the variable
$img = "ImageFiles/" . uniqid(time()) . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"], $img);
...
//Dont pass data directly to bind_param store it in a variable
$insert->bind_param("s", $img);
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to throw an error at all, but I think the problem is that it is binding a null value as I think it is not retrieving the last "ImageId". I have realised I only got 2 hours of the bounty left so very quickly how would you change the php code so that it retrieves the last "ImageId"? Assuming that is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Bind with mysqli works with references to variables.  I dont think your last argument in the second bind command references the way you expect it to.

Assign the the last argument $_POST['numQuestion'][$i] to a variable and use this variable in the bind method call.  I am guessing this is either not defined, evaluating to null, and the bind is failing since you can't bind a null as a string or bind cannot use a multidimensional array since itexpects a variable passed as reference.

Try this:

```
//Below will set a default value of empty string if the POST variable is not set
$postVar = isset($_POST['numQuestion'][$i])?$_POST['numQuestion'][$i]:'';
$insertimagequestion->bind_param("sss", $lastID, $sessid, $postVar);
```

After doing this, if you see entries in the DB with a '' in the QuestionId column,  $_POST['numQuestion'][$i]  isn't being set and you have something wrong elsewhere in your code having nothing to do with DB access.

Comment: Lets assume that the second bind isn't working, how would you change the php code to make it work? I can't seem to get the error to be shown as that the upload file page is on a seperate php file to the page which actually does the uploading using a plugin and AJAX

Comment: @user1394925 The newly added code above will protect against null values being bound as well as alleviating any reference issues with working with a multi-dimensional array.  You might want to make the default $postVar be something other than the empty string '' or check for a valid value before trying the insert.

Comment: Nothing is inserting into the Image_QUestion Table, no errors appearing on the imageupload.php page but the reason I believe it can't show any errors is because the AJAX uploader and the php script which does the uploading is on a seperate page and they both only link up using AJAX, they link up on the background

Comment: @user1394925  Assuming $lastID, $sessid, and $postVar are legimitate strings, the bind/execute should be working. You might be getting a key conflict in the DB or something like that.  var_dump the results of both insert objects after executing them into your php error log and take a look at them.  That's the easiest way to inspect if you can't pass them back to the AJAX call for display.

Comment: @user1394925 I meant to say dump the result from the execution of the inserts.  you can get that with $insert->get_result() and $insertimagequestion->get_result()

Comment: I tried the $insert->get_result() and $insertimagequestion->get_result() but nothing is being outputted at all still

Comment: @user1394925  Did you do something like this: `$result = $insert->get__result(); $resultText = var_export($result, true); error_log($resultText); ` and then checked your error logs and saw nothing?

Comment: No error Ray, nothing in the firebug. I added a foriegn key constraint between Image table and Image_Question table by linking the ImageId field, I just don't know what problem is

Comment: @user1394925 Did you check your PHP error logs?  /var/log/phperrors.php and the apache error logs?

Comment: This code `$result = $insert->get__result(); $resultText = var_export($result, true); error_log($resultText);` isn't actually working.

Comment: @user1394925 Go brute force.  After every line dump every variable to your error log--something is not what it seems.  If nothing logs to the log you've got bigger problems.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to figure out where could be the failure.

There is no problem with second query and you get successfully last insert id. I used static values for the variables for second query it worked fine. Even you can hardcode values n check out.

Take care of the foll:

1. Does bind params get the all the values?

> ```
> print_r() $lastID, $sessid, $_POST['numQuestion'][$i] 
> This Will not create problem unless database has contraints of not accepting empty or null values.
> ```

1. Make use of the check condition to find where its going wrong.

> ```
> if (!$insertimagequestion = $mysqli->prepare("$imagequestionsql")) {
>     // Handle errors with prepare operation here
>     echo "Prepare statement err";
> }
>
> if ($insert->errno) {
>   // Handle query error here
>     echo "insert execution error";
> }
> ```

Though its an ajax you can use Developer Tool of Chome to debug ajax requests.

> 1. Press F12 to open the **Developer Tool** in Chrome
> 2. Go to Network Tab >> Perform action for ajax requests to be sent on your form >> you can find the ajax requests sent >> click on it >> Click on  the "Response" Tab you will find the error if you have
>      echoed or the response. So, echo error and print_r() to help debugging

Comment: I will try your answer, $lastID and $sessid go in columns where it would not allow null values but this should not be a problem as I want to insert those values in those columns, right?